# Animation Console App 3 dot loader, how would I go about this?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a console app and I would like a loader animation, for example  3 dots that appear one at a time until it reaches the third dot then restarts the loop and does it all over again. Could someone show me how to do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the loop in a background thread:

```
import threading
import time
import sys

should_quit = False

num_dots = 3

def print_dots():
    count = 0
    while not should_quit:
        time.sleep(.25)
        if 0 == count % num_dots:
            print(f"\r{' ' * num_dots}\r", end='')
        print('.', end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        count += 1

t = None
try:
    t = threading.Thread(target=print_dots)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
except:
   print("Error: unable to start thread")

try:
    input()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

should_quit = True
t.join()
```